# Mysql SUM query is not showing all other column

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I'm Trying to Sum the price of the selected topping and show all the names of selected topping, is it possible to do so ?

here is the query

```
SELECT tord.Kode_topping_order, 
       t.Nama_topping, 
       SUM(t.Harga_topping) AS 'Total Topping' 
FROM topping_order tord 
JOIN topping t ON tord.Kode_Topping = t.Kode_topping 
WHERE tord.Kode_Produk_Order = 39
```

the output :

[image: Query]

However if I Group by Nama_topping the output will be like this:

[image: Query2]

Is it possible to have All of the Name of topping and all the Total Topping is filled with 12000 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`:

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(tord.Kode_topping_order, 'TOTAL'),
    COALESCE(t.Nama_topping, 'TOTAL'),
    SUM(t.Harga_topping) AS 'Total Topping'
FROM topping_order tord
INNER JOIN topping t
    ON tord.Kode_Topping = t.Kode_topping
WHERE
    tord.Kode_Produk_Order = 39 AND
    (tord.Kode_topping_order IS NULL OR t.Nama_topping IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY
    tord.Kode_topping_order,
    t.Nama_topping
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: so it added a Total column to sum it all huh ...

Comment: so is it not possible to make all the column of Total_topping is 12000
and the Nama Topping is all of the nama topping, because I'm planning to store the data to the table in php, so I guess ill do it with multiple queries, 

thanks for the answer

Comment: Not sure what else you want here.  If you want to see a new column with the table total sum, then add `SUM(SUM(t.Harga_topping)) OVER ()` to the select clause.

Comment: Ahh yess something like that

Comment: ah yeah forget to mark it answered

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery.

If you can give the both tables data that you have joined I will type the
query of course if it is possible to give me the both table data.

The subquery will be like this:

```
SELECT
Kode_topping_order,
(SELECT Nama_topping, SUM(Harga_topping) AS Total_Topping FROM topping) 
FROM topping_order tord 
JOIN topping t ON tord.Kode_Topping = t.Kode_topping 
WHERE tord.Kode_Produk_Order = 39
```

Comment: it says ``Operand should contain 1 column(s)``